# How to handle null input parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

I know in Scala a method should never return `null`... but what's about input parameters? Given the following code snippet...

```
object MyObject {

    def myMethod(p: String): Option[String] = {
        if (p == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("p is null.")
        ...
    }
}
```

... is the way I check `p` correct? Is there any recommendation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The convention is that Scala code does not use nulls (with a tiny number of exceptions, which should immediately be fixed when using those library functions).

Thus, a null from Scala is a sign that something has gone wrong (at least a [PBCAK](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pbcak)), so you may as well throw an exception.  This is not routine operation; this is something seriously screwed up.  Catch the exception wherever you catch serious screw-ups.  Catching an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a `NullPointerException` adds no extra information.  Just leave the original alone.

If the code comes from Java, the canonical way of dealing with it is to wrap it in `Option`, which will convert `null` to `None`.  Then you probably don't even need to throw an exception; just return a `None`.

```
def myMethod(p: String) = Option(p).map(_.toLowerCase)
```

If you cannot continue when it is null, then you need to consider whether an informative exception would help.  `Option(p).orElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null!"))` is one compact way of expressing the exception-throwing sentiment.

In Scala 2.10, you can also wrap things in `scala.util.Try(...)` which will automatically catch and package the exception for you.  If you want a packaged exception instead of a thrown one, this is the way to go.  (And use `Try` instead of `Option`.)

```
import scala.util.Try
def myMethod(p: String) = Try(p.toLowerCase)
```

Finally, for more general handling of alternative outcomes, use `Either`.  The convention for error handling is that the expected output is a `Right(whatever)`, while `Left(whatever)` indicates that something went wrong.

Comment: Since I'm writing an API, I think the more appropriate construct is Try.

Comment: Be careful when wrapping null values in an Option though. If you rely on type inference, you might run into trouble sometimes. For instance, if you do Option(null).map(_ + 1) you'll get an exemption. However, doing Option(null: String).map(_.toLowerCase) is fine

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways and your way is one.

You could also use:

```
require(p != null, "p is null.")
```

or the "more functional" way would be to use `Option`:

```
def myMethod(p: String): Option[String] = {

  // no exception
  for {
    pp <- Option(p)
  } yield p + " foo bar"
}
```

edit:

or if you want the error without an exception thrown you can use `Either`:

```
def myMethod(p: String): Either[Exception, String] = {
  if(p == null) Left(new IllegalArgumentException("p is null."))
  else Right(p + "foo bar")
}
```

Comment: It begs the question though; why not just have a method taking in an Option[String]?

Comment: This is why scala is so screwed up language. To me an Option in method signature indicates that the parameter is optional. What if the parameter is not optional and you don't want the caller to pass null or empty (call is using Java)?

Sometimes I wonder why people just don't stick to simplicity and use Java / C++. It can be verbose, but it is readable and has advanced well enough these days to be used for distributed programming.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala idiom is essentially "don't use null values ever". So unless you're writing an API that needs to accommodate filthy Java users, I just wouldn't worry about it. Otherwise, you're going to end up inserting this boilerplate check for every parameter on every method you write.

Your beautiful one-line methods

```
def square(x: String): String = math.pow(x.toInt, 2).toInt.toString
```

will turn into something awkward like

```
def square(x: String): String = 
    if (x == null) throw new NullPointerException()
    math.pow(x.toInt, 2).toInt.toString
}
```

or

```
def square(x: String): String = Option(x) match {
    case Some(x) => math.pow(x.toInt, 2).toInt.toString
    case None => throw new NullPointerException()
}
```

How dreadful.

Comment: `Double` is primitive.  It can't be `null`.

Comment: Changed it to a new example with Strings :)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach is something like:

```
object HandlingInputValidation {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("A1: " + handleInput("Correct ") + " END")
    println("A2: " + handleInput("Correct") + " END")
    println("A3: " + handleInput("") + " END")
    println("A4: " + handleInput(" ") + " END")
    println("A5: " + handleInput(null) + " END")
  }

  def handleInput(data: String): Option[String] = {
    Option(data).map(_.trim.toLowerCase)
  }
 }
```

In this case, `null` will be `None`, and spaces will be trimmed.